# How fixed a navigation to the center on scroll?

Tags: css, position, fixed

I have a navigation centered with a width of 80% and when I scroll the page, at certain point of time I fixed the header to top, when I do this it floats to the left instead of staying in the middle. How can I keep the navigation to the center and fixed to the top.

html

```
<div id="foo">
</div>
<div id="nav">
</div>
<div id="bar">
</div>
```

css

```
#foo{
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
}
#bar{
    height:1000px;
    width:100%;
}

#nav{
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFCC00;
}
.fixed-nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

script

```
var bottom = $('#nav').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function(){    
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > bottom){ 
        $('#nav').addClass('fixed-nav'); 
    }
    else{
        $('#nav').removeClass('fixed-nav');
    }
});
```

Here is my code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6hucevmk/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to center the nav in another way. If you have set a fixed `width` (80% in this case), you can use simply `margin-left: 10%;` instead `margin: 0 auto;`.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/6hucevmk/2/)

Note: I also set `body{ margin: 0; }` to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `left: 10%` to `.fixed-nav` fixes this. Also, you need to add `body { margin: 0px; }` in your CSS otherwise the `#nav` grows in size a bit while scrolling down.

Here's the edited [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4kvaq5b5/)